# Google cloud storage namespace

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to upload file to my storage. I use this code

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "YOUR SERVICE EMAIL HERE";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"PATH TO YOUR p12 FILE HERE", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService ss = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "YOUR APPLICATION NAME HERE",
});

var fileobj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object()
{
    Bucket = "YOUR BUCKET NAME HERE",
    Name = "file"
};

Stream stream = null;
stream = new MemoryStream(img);

Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload insmedia;
insmedia = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(ss, fileobj, "YOUR BUCKET NAME HERE", stream, "image/jpeg");
insmedia.Upload();
```

I made a new project -> Console application ( C# ) and I have problem with references I think because I'm getting those errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Google.Apis' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

My usings:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please help me :)

Comment: `using Google.Apis.Storage` ?

Comment: There isn't method like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a NuGet package - you should install the [`Google.Apis.Storage.v1` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Storage.v1) in your project. After that, you should be able to add a `using` directive of

```
using Google.Apis.Storage.v1;
```

... and use code of:

```
var insmedia = new ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(ss, fileobj,
    "YOUR BUCKET NAME HERE", stream, "image/jpeg");
insmedia.Upload();
```

(After setting the bucket name, of course.)

Comment: Thanks it works, I don't know why I didn't do it before